# PHP ODBC fetch cyrillic character from mssql

Tags: php, odbc, ssms, cyrillic

I fetch cyrillic data from mssql with Php odbc,

it shown as question mark "?"

I use "Turkish_CI_AS" Collation and column type is NVARCHAR

Besides, on .net project has shown correctly that character

What should I do? Can anyone assist on me?

here is my PHP code example

```
<?
$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=XXX;Database=dtbs;SET NAMES 'utf8';SET CHARACTER SET utf8;MARS_Connection=yes";
    $my_sql = odbc_connect($dsn, 'user', 'pass');

    $query = "SELECT col FROM Tbl WHERE id=?";
    $prepared = odbc_prepare($my_sql, $query);
    if(!$prepared) die("could not prepare statement");

    $params=array('1');

    if(odbc_execute($prepared, $params)) {
        $rows = odbc_fetch_array($prepared);

        $col=$rows["col"];
        echo $col;
    }
?>
```

I tried many things for solution, but no result.

here is screenshot from SSMS

[image]

and screenshot from chrome

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`$content = mb_convert_encoding($col, 'utf-8', 'windows-1251');
echo $content;`

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no.